# Swift TableView Missing Return

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYRR4.png)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if indexPath.row == 1
            {
                let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KonuDetayKonuTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! KonuDetayKonuTableViewCell
                cell.lblBaslik.text = arrayYorumData[indexPath.row].baslik
                cell.lblKullaniciAdiVeTarih.text = arrayYorumData[indexPath.row].uye + " - " + arrayYorumData[indexPath.row].tarih
                cell.lblYazi.text = arrayYorumData[indexPath.row].yazi
                cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
                if singleton.username != arrayYorumData[indexPath.row].uye{
                    cell.btnDüzenle.isHidden = true
                }

                return cell
            }

        }
```

> Hi I'm getting an error here. How can I solve the problem?
>   I did not have a problem with the previous version but I started
>   getting this error in the version I just updated

Comment: Think about it: What if `indexPath.row != 1` ?

Comment: thanks, problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

you're only returning when indexPath.row is = 1, take care of any value.

you could solve this by adding this to the end of the function:

```
return UITableViewCell()
```

but generally you'll want to dequeue a reusable cell from your table view, and set up the cells how you want them